# How to retrieve the images which I didn't upload from the MySql database in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, database, image

I am using the database which my friend created. There is image column in products table in Mysql database. When I try to display the image, I only see raw image data. I also don't have images in public folder or storage folder since I didn't create the database.

Controller

```
public function home() {
    $totalSale = Order::sum('total_amount');
    $formattedTotalSale = number_format($totalSale, 2, '.', ',');
    return view('home.home', [
        'products'  => Product::first(),
        'users'     => User::latest()->get(),
        'orders'    => Order::latest()->get(),
        'totalSale' => $formattedTotalSale, 
    ]);
}
```

home.blade.php

```
@props(['products', 'orders', 'users', 'totalSale'])
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img src="{{$products->image}}" alt="">
</div>
```